# Switch keyboard layouts for other programs

Tags: c#, wpf

I write program that should change the layout of the program, which is in focus. I have a code that Gets the ID of current keyboard layout:

```
const int KL_NAMELENGTH = 9;
    const uint KLF_ACTIVATE = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern long LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern long GetKeyboardLayoutName(System.Text.StringBuilder pwszKLID);

    public static string getKLName()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder name = new System.Text.StringBuilder(KL_NAMELENGTH);
        GetKeyboardLayoutName(name);
        return name.ToString();
    }
```

For example:
EN - "00000409"
DE-  "00000407"
FR-  "0000040C"

Also I have the following code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);    

 private void ChangeLang(String code)
 {

   PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), 0x0050, 2, 0);

 }
```

Nowadays, calling the function **ChangeLang**, the program switches the current language to the next. But I need it to function ChangeLang passed on the message to other programs, on what layout switch (use code layout). How is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hhwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

private const uint WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST = 0x0050;
private const uint KLF_ACTIVATE = 1;

private const string en_US = "00000409";

private static void ChangeLanguage(string code)
{
    PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, IntPtr.Zero, LoadKeyboardLayout(code, KLF_ACTIVATE));
}
```